# What's wrong with this ASP.NET code.... ? (Datagrid + Imagebutton)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "Hold" Then
        Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = CType(CType(sender, Control).Parent.Parent, GridViewRow)
        Dim index As Integer = gvRow.RowIndex
        Dim myRow As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(index)
        'Find the checkbox
        Dim lab5 As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Label5"), Label)
        Dim label2 As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Label2"), Label)
        Dim label4 As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Label4"), Label)
        Dim label22 As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Label22"), Label)
        Me.Response.Redirect("Select_seats.aspx?s_no=" & label22.Text.ToString & "&" & "journey=" & Label6.Text & "&" & "seater=" & label4.Text & "&" & "sleeper=" & label2.Text & "&" & "service=" & lab5.Text.ToString)
    End If
End Sub
```

this code giving error :

in this line

im gvRow As GridViewRow = CType(CType(sender, Control).Parent.Parent, GridViewRow)

**error :**

Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.vendors_select_service_aspx' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'.

Comment: Why `& "&" &"<string>"` instead of `& "&<string>"`? Why do you invoke `ToString` on `lab5.Text` but nothing else? Why do you spell `What's` with a lower case `w`, a `z` instead of an `s` and no apostrophe?

Comment: the code is mentioned above already ,,,,,

Comment: @user559800  the code from the `.aspx` is what @bAN needs to see.

Comment: the ASP part.. with the gridview.. you mention only the code behind in VB

Comment: Why do you iterate all rows in Grid? Therefore you are rediredcting on the first row and not on the row that causes the "Hold-Command".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you iterate all rows in Grid? Therefore you are redirecting on the first row and not on the row that causes the "Hold-Command".  The [NamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) of any control in the GridViewRow is the GridViewRow itself and this is what [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol.aspx) needs to get the reference to your labels.

```
    If e.CommandName = "Hold" Then
        Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(e.CommandSource, Control).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
        Dim lab5 As Label = DirectCast(row.FindControl("Label5"), Label)
        Dim label2 As Label = DirectCast(row.FindControl("Label2"), Label)
        Dim label4 As Label = DirectCast(row.FindControl("Label4"), Label)
        Dim label6 As Label = DirectCast(row.FindControl("label6"), Label)
        Dim label22 As Label = DirectCast(row.FindControl("Label22"), Label)
        Me.Response.Redirect("Select_seats.aspx?s_no=" & label22.Text.ToString & "&" & "journey=" & label6.Text & "&" & "seater=" & label4.Text & "&" & "sleeper=" & label2.Text & "&" & "service=" & lab5.Text.ToString)
    End If
```

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.vendors_select_service_aspx' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'.

Comment: My fault, sender is the gridView and its NamingContainer is the Page. Use the e.CommandSource property to get the reference to your Imagebutton. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of theChrisKent is the right direction, assuming you're using TemplateField you can get the index with such code:

```
Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = CType(CType(sender, Control).Parent.Parent, GridViewRow)
Dim index As Integer = gvRow.RowIndex
```

If still no luck do as you were already told and post your `.aspx` code so we can help instead of groping in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

Switch your code to this:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
  If e.CommandName = "Hold" Then        
    Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
    Dim myRow As GridViewRow = GridView1.Rows(index)
    'Find the checkbox
    Dim lab5 As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Label5"), Label)
    Dim label2 As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Label2"), Label)
    Dim label4 As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Label4"), Label)
    Dim label22 As Label = DirectCast(myRow.FindControl("Label22"), Label)
    Me.Response.Redirect("Select_seats.aspx?s_no=" & label22.Text.ToString & "&" & "journey=" & Label6.Text & "&" & "seater=" & label4.Text & "&" & "sleeper=" & label2.Text & "&" & "service=" & lab5.Text.ToString)
  End If
End Sub
```

Also add this (be sure to switch the holdButton retrieval code to match the control type and index you are using)

```
Sub GridView1_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCreated

  ' The GridViewCommandEventArgs class does not contain a 
  ' property that indicates which row's command button was
  ' clicked. To identify which row's button was clicked, use 
  ' the button's CommandArgument property by setting it to the 
  ' row's index.
  If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

    ' Retrieve the LinkButton control from the first column.
    Dim holdButton As LinkButton = CType(e.Row.Cells(0).Controls(0), LinkButton)

    ' Set the LinkButton's CommandArgument property with the
    ' row's index.
    holdButton.CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()

  End If

End Sub
```

This code taken from an example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: Showing that error in Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)

Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the RowCreated Event Handler

Comment: Both of these event handlers should be in your code behind.  The RowCreated Event Handler can be cut and paste beneath the RowCommand Event Handler if you'd like.  If you give us the portion of the ASPX page with the GridView, I can update the Event Handler to find the holdButton correctly.