# redirect gridview selected row data to two different pages on clicking on two different select button asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

[image]

Ihave a gridview item template field namely Status as mentioned above ...

i want when user click on hold button of particular row then the record from the particular row is transfered to another page. ... means.... if i click on the hold button of 1st row of gridview then seats=35 and booking closed =08:00:00 PM willbe trasferred to

```
Me.Response.Redirect("Select_seats.aspx?s_no=" & label22.Text.ToString & "&" & "journey=" & label6.Text & "&" & "seater=" & label4.Text & "&" & "sleeper=" & label2.Text & "&" & "service=" & lab5.Text.ToString) ..
```

and if i click on the manage button of same row then the record of that row will be transferred to

```
Me.Response.Redirect("Select_nfo.aspx?s_no=" & label22.Text.ToString & "&" & "journey=" & label6.Text & "&" & "seater=" & label4.Text & "&" & "sleeper=" & label2.Text & "&" & "service=" & lab5.Text.ToString)
```

Comment: @user559800 So if you know the url you want to redirect to, and you've got the `Response.Redirect` to do it, what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming from your [previous, similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578151/whats-wrong-with-my-this-code-asp-net-datagrid-imagebutton), i'm not sure what problems you actually have because you already had 99% of the answer.

```
   Private Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
        Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(e.CommandSource, Control).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
        Dim lab5 As Label = DirectCast(row.FindControl("Label5"), Label)
        Dim label2 As Label = DirectCast(row.FindControl("Label2"), Label)
        Dim label4 As Label = DirectCast(row.FindControl("Label4"), Label)
        Dim label6 As Label = DirectCast(row.FindControl("label6"), Label)
        Dim label22 As Label = DirectCast(row.FindControl("Label22"), Label)

        If e.CommandName = "Hold" Then
            Me.Response.Redirect("Select_seats.aspx?s_no=" & label22.Text.ToString & "&" & "journey=" & label6.Text & "&" & "seater=" & label4.Text & "&" & "sleeper=" & label2.Text & "&" & "service=" & lab5.Text.ToString)
        ElseIf e.CommandName = "Manage" Then
            Me.Response.Redirect("Select_nfo.aspx?s_no=" & label22.Text.ToString & "&" & "journey=" & label6.Text & "&" & "seater=" & label4.Text & "&" & "sleeper=" & label2.Text & "&" & "service=" & lab5.Text.ToString)
        End If
   End Sub
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

this error in this line ...this line is highlighted with yellow line

      Me.Response.Redirect("Select_seats.aspx?s_no=" & label22.Text.ToString & "&" & "journey=" & label6.Text & "&" & "seater=" & label4.Text & "&" & "sleeper=" & label2.Text & "&" & "service=" & lab5.Text.ToString)